# How to convert categorical variable to numerical in pandas without increasing size of data?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to convert categorical data into numerical using `get_dummies()` but the size of data increases from `1 X 1` to `1 X 22` because there are 22 different categorical variables.

I used `get_dummies()` from pandas.

Code:

```
data['program_id'].unique()

cols_to_transform = data['program_id'].loc[:]

df_with_dummies = pd.get_dummies( data=cols_to_transform )
```

How can I convert categorical data of my column into numerical without increasing the size of data.

Screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can using `factorize`

```
df['columns']=pd.factorize(df['columns'])[0]#df.columns.astype('category').cat.codes
```

Or `LabelEncoder` from `sklearn`